C++ Runtime polymorphism calling unexpected override when multiple classes are inherited
I am trying to create a GUI system with C++11 where, perhaps like Godot, every "node" has a very specific purpose such as grouping other nodes, drawing a rectangle, or detecting when a specific area of the screen is pressed down. Some parts of the code are getting a little repetitive as switch statements will determine a node's type and cast it appropriately, only to call the exact same function name in each case.
I thought I could clean this up by abstracting each node a bit more so the Rectangle class would inherit not just the BaseNode class, but also the Visibility class to specify that it has a Draw() function to call. By making Visibility::Draw() a virtual function and overriding it in each derived class, I should be able to replace the long switch statement with a single line that casts the BaseNode* to a Visibility* and call Draw() on that to display the rectangle, circle, image, polygon, or whatever specific functionality that individual node is programmed to have.
I wrote up this theoretically good solution yet found that it would call neither Rectangle::Draw() nor Visibility::Draw() but instead some random part of memory!
I eventually pinpointed the issue and wrote up this small demo to replicate it. Casting pRect to a Visibility* and calling the Draw() function will execute Rectangle::BasicFunc() inherited from BaseNode instead of Rectangle::Draw() inherited from Visibility.
#include <iostream>

class BaseNode {
    public:
        virtual void BasicFunc() {
            std::cout << "BaseNode BasicFunc()" << std::endl;
        }
};

class Visibility {
    public:
        virtual void Draw() {
            std::cout << "Visibility Draw()" << std::endl;
        }
};

class Rectangle : public BaseNode, public Visibility {
    public:
        void BasicFunc() {
            std::cout << "Rectangle BasicFunc()" << std::endl;
        }
        void Draw() {
            std::cout << "Rectangle Draw()" << std::endl;
        }
};

int main() {
    BaseNode* pRect = new Rectangle;
    
    ((Visibility*)pRect)->Draw(); // Calls Rectangle::BasicFunc() instead of Rectangle::Draw()

    return 0;
}

Some other testing I've done:

Casting pRect to a Rectangle* instead will correctly call Rectangle::Draw(), but then it's back to the bulky switch statement.
Removing the virtual keyword from Visibility::Draw will make the Draw() call execute Visibility::Draw(). Correct function name but not the correct class.
Order of overriding functions in the Rectangle class does not matter.
Initializing pRect as a BaseNode* will make BasicFunc() always work.
Initializing pRect as a Visibility* will make Draw() always work.
Casting pRect from a BaseNode* to a Visibility* will make Draw() always fail and call BasicFunc() instead. (The current issue)
Casting pRect from a Visibility* to a BaseNode* will make BasicFunc() always fail and call Draw() instead.
Initializing pRect as a void* will make both BasicFunc() and Draw() call the function associated with Rectangle's first inherited class.

I am completely unsure how to go about fixing this. Any advice is appreciated!

Use dynamic_cast.

Hopefully lesson learned: never C-style cast class pointers and references.

Running with address sanitizer indicates the problem immediately:

runtime error: member call on address 0x602000000010 which does not point to an object of type 'Visibility'

The issue here is that you cannot directly cast a BaseNode object to a Visibility object because there is no such relationship between these two classes. What you have here is undefined behavior.
Because a static_cast is impossible here, the compiler resorts to a reinterpret_cast, which in this case leads to you invoking the virtual table of a different class from the one the compiler thinks it's using.
One possible workaround is to use use dynamic_cast:
auto pVisibility = dynamic_cast<Visibility*>(pRect);
if (pVisibility) {
    pVisibility->Draw();
}

However, using this can often be seen as a "code smell". There are various other approaches you may use, but that's entirely up to your other design considerations.
As an aside, you should add a virtual destructor to BaseNode, because right now trying to delete pRect; has the potential to cause undefined behavior:
class BaseNode {
    public:
        virtual ~BaseNode() = default;
        virtual void BasicFunc() {
            std::cout << "BaseNode BasicFunc()" << std::endl;
        }
};


This is how I would implement something like this

Make interfaces concrete by modeling them as pure abstract baseclasses (better for unit testability and dependency injection later)
Model code reuse by providing default implementations per interface. I usuall y use CRTP/mixin to avoid diamond inheritance later (you can derive from specific implementations)
Never use naked/new delete. It is NOT recommended to do so anymore in C++ see C++ core guidelines
Live demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/LTdAgEQr9


#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// keep interfaces abstract (no implementation yet)

class IBaseNode
{
public:
    virtual ~IBaseNode() = default; // classes with virtual methods must also have virtual destructors.
    virtual void BasicFunc() = 0;
};

// allow mixin of default implementation (CRTP)
// this way you will not fall into the trap
// of creating a design with diamond inheritance later

template<typename base_t>
class IBaseNodeImpl :
    public IBaseNode
{
public:
    virtual void BasicFunc()
    {
        // do not use std::endl; unless you really have to flush
        // in templates you need to use this
        std::cout << "BaseNode BasicFunc(), value = " << this->m_value << "\n";
    }
private:
    int m_value{ 42 };
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class IVisibility
{
public:
    virtual ~IVisibility() = default;
    virtual void Draw() const = 0;
};

template<typename base_t>
class IVisibilityImpl :
    public IVisibility
{
public:
    void Draw() const override
    {
        std::cout << "Visibility Draw()\n";
        if (get_visibility())
        {
            std::cout << "Visible\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invisible\n";
        }
    }

protected:
    // never expose private members directly
    // for refactorability later 

    void set_visibility(bool is_visible)
    {
        m_is_visible = true;
    }

    bool get_visibility() const noexcept
    {
        return m_is_visible;
    }

private:
    bool m_is_visible{ false };
};

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Rectangle final :
    public IBaseNodeImpl<Rectangle>,
    public IVisibilityImpl<Rectangle>
{
public:
    Rectangle()
    {
        std::cout << "Rectangle constructed\n";

        // You can manage visibility from within
        // the rectangle too
        set_visibility(true);
    }

    ~Rectangle()
    {
        std::cout << "Rectangle destructed\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    //BaseNode* pRect = new Rectangle;  <== don't use new in C++ anymore, you should use std::make_unique (to avoid memory leaks)

    std::unique_ptr<IBaseNode> rectangle = std::make_unique<Rectangle>();
    rectangle->BasicFunc();

    auto visibility = dynamic_cast<IVisibility*>(rectangle.get());
    visibility->Draw();

    return 0;
}

